# How to use built/compressed Dojo to resolve Dojo modules ref'ed from tests?

Tags: dojo, intern

Currently, with my Intern setup, I'm using an unbuilt Dojo build when running my Intern tests; like, for example, a test module loads app/ProductModuleA, and ProductModuleA references and loads dojo/request. I need to have the dojo/request.js file in the appropriate directory structure in order for the module to be resolved without errors and therefore the test to be able to run. Our product code does use a built dojo.js file and our previous DOH tests were able to use this, too, without any issues--I don't understand how that worked because I don't know anything really about building Dojo.

I know I've seen snippets in various Internet forums (like here) and the Intern User Guide that Intern supports source maps, which I guess suggests it's possible to use a built dojo.js file in conjunction with running Intern, but I haven't found anything at all in detail. Insights, or pointers to documentation or examples that so far I haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the benefits of AMD is that you don't have to do anything special to your code when switching between a built and unbuilt Dojo. The first time you load a dependency using an unbuilt Dojo, the loader requests it over the network and then caches the result. Subsequent loads use the cached dependency. The loading process works the same with a built Dojo; the main difference is that all the modules built into the built Dojo are pre-cached. The loader doesn't have to request them over the network the first time because they start out in the module cache.

For Intern to use a built Dojo, you just need to make sure you're using the built Dojo as your loader during tests. You can do this by setting the [`useLoader` option](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader) in your Intern config.

Answer (score -1):

I tried what Jason suggested and it still didn't work--I was getting 404s for a Dojo_ROOT.js module, though nothing in tests or product files explicitly load that. I'm sure this is due to something unique in my product's build environment. That's okay, I will just use the Dojo source for now and return to this later.